# How can I make a process started with subprocess.Popen to be able to use the packages installed?

Tags: python, text, package, subprocess, popen

I am using `subprocess.Popen('python txtfile')` to run a txt file in python. It works perfectly fine when I use it with built-in modules such as `tkinter` or `random` but when I try to use external packages (that I have previously installed. The code works in a .py file but not when I run the txt file with `subprocess.Popen()`) it shows (when I use the NumPy package:

```
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: Also when I run the same command from the command line (python txtfile) it works! Why isn't it working with subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have multiple python versions on your system, uninstall them all including ones from Microsoft store and setup one from python.org and tick the box to "Add python to PATH" at the end of installation.

Another way is to call your interpreter from sys.executable

```py
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,'txtfile.py'])
```

which will call the correct interpreter.

Comment: I only have python 3.9 installed.

Comment: @hippopotamus try the second paragraph in the answer